# Parameters to SQL in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-devtools, web-sql

Chrome's Developer Tools have a handy prompt on the Resources page where I can execute SQL on my actual WebSQL database. But if the SQL is parameterised like this:

```
select * from SomeTable where ImportantField = ?
```

I get a message like this:

> Number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count

I know this is a SQLite message, but I don't see an obvious way to supply the arguments in Chrome Dev Tools. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You are not possibly trying to execute that SQL as-is on the prompt, are you ?
If yes, then obviously you are wrong.

why do you care about ? when you are executing your SQL on console, why not simply use the value.

```
select * from SomeTable where ImportantField = 'yourValue'
```

Comment: It just depends on the context. It's not an issue in this simple example, but a large statement with several parameters, it would be a lot easier to simply receive a prompt for each param - like in virtually every SQL tool ever devised. Especially since CDT doesn't exactly have a top-notch editor there.